# How to get the image size dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, dynamic, size

I am new to ios.In my project there is an imageview for that imageview images are given dynamically(user given an image)based on the image size(width&height) i have to do some changes.So how i get the size of image?

Comment: Use UIImage's size property !!!!!!

Comment: yourImageView.image.size :)

Answer (score -1):

Using UIImage size property

```
UIImage *yourImage ...
yourImage.size.width ...
yourImage.size.height ...
```

Answer (score -1):

That Is duplicate Question But i dont know how to tag as a duplicate but steel I answer you that must duplicate.

1st way:

```
image.size.height;

image.size.width;
```

2nd way:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: yourUIImage];

CGFloat height = imageView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat width = imageView.frame.size.width;
```

If you have any problem related with this answer please comment me....:)

Comment: Who is Tag as a down vote that please give a reason for that,